# how to create a nested logs in UIautomation ios

Tags: ios, ios-ui-automation

How to create a nested logs in UIautomation ios like the one produced by logElementTree()

I tried doing the following:

```
UIALogger.logStart("Log parent Started");

UIALogger.logStart("Log child Started");

UIALogger.logMessage("Message 1");

UIALogger.logPass("Log child passed");

UIALogger.logPass("Log Parent passed");
```

But this isn't creating a nested logs in the Instruments window

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible. For whatever reason, Apple isn't exposing the ability to have a nested log output like you get with `logElementTree()`. Every call to `logStart()` starts the log grouping over again.

Do file a bug over at [bugreporter.apple.com](http://bugreporter.apple.com/). Even though it feels like a black hole where bugs go in and nothing gets accomplished, they really do use the bug reporter to determine what to fix next.